# jQuery's $.append() breaks my loop, why?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to draw some text in an array of colors to the screen. However, when using jQuery's `$.append()` with the `<span>` tag, it stops my loop and does not color anything. This is what it looks like:

```
        var pixelsjson = '[{"red":232,"green":255,"blue":255},{"red":230,"green":255,"blue":255},{"red":229,"green":255,"blue":255},{"red":228,"green":255,"blue":255},{"red":227,"green":255,"blue":255},{"red":226,"green":255,"blue":255},{"red":224,"green":255,"blue":255},{"red":223,"green":255,"blue":255},{"red":222,"green":255,"blue":255},{"red":221,"green":254,"blue":255},{"red":220,"green":254,"blue":255},{"red":219,"green":254,"blue":255},{"red":217,"green":253,"blue":255},{"red":215,"green":253,"blue":255},{"red":213,"green":251,"blue":255},{"red":210,"green":250,"blue":255},{"red":207,"green":248,"blue":255},{"red":203,"green":246,"blue":255},{"red":200,"green":244,"blue":255},{"red":196,"green":242,"blue":255},{"red":96,"green":247,"blue":154},{"red":0,"green":255,"blue":54},{"red":0,"green":255,"blue":54},{"red":0,"green":255,"blue":54},{"red":0,"green":255,"blue":54},{"red":0,"green":255,"blue":54},{"red":0,"green":255,"blue":54},{"red":0,"green":255,"blue":54},{"red":0,"green":255,"blue":54},{"red":0,"green":255,"blue":54},{"red":0,"green":255,"blue":54},{"red":0,"green":255,"blue":54},{"red":0,"green":255,"blue":54},{"red":0,"green":255,"blue":54}]]';

        var pixels = JSON.parse(pixelsjson);
        var imgheight = 80;
        var imgwidth = 106;

        $(document).ready(function () {
            var drawcount = 0;
            for (var i = 0; i < imgheight; i++) {
                $("#image").append("<br>");
                for (var j = 0; j < imgwidth; j++) {
                    $("#image").append("<span style='color: rgba(" + pixels[i][j].red + " , " + pixels[i][j].green + " , " + pixels[i][j].blue + ", 1);'>");
                    switch (drawcount % 18) {
                        case 0:
                            $("#image").append("/");
                            break;
                        case 2:
                            $("#image").append("-");
                            break;
                        case 3:
                            $("#image").append("/");
                            break;
                        case 4:
                            $("#image").append("-");
                            break;
                        case 5:
                            $("#image").append("/");
                            break;
                        case 6:
                            $("#image").append("-");
                            break;
                        case 7:
                            $("#image").append("(");
                            break;
                        case 8:
                            $("#image").append("8");
                            break;
                        case 9:
                            $("#image").append("8");
                            break;
                        case 10:
                            $("#image").append(")");
                            break;
                        case 11:
                            $("#image").append("-");
                            break;
                        case 12:
                            $("#image").append("\\");
                            break;
                        case 13:
                            $("#image").append("-");
                            break;
                        case 14:
                            $("#image").append("\\");
                            break;
                        case 15:
                            $("#image").append("-");
                            break;
                        case 16:
                            $("#image").append("\\");
                            break;
                        case 17:
                            $("#image").append("  ");
                            break;
                    }
                    $("#image").append("</span>");
                    drawcount++;
                }
            }
        });
```

This is the html:

```
<div id="image" style="font-family:Courier New, Courier, monospace; font-size: 10px;"></div>
```

I updated the script to:

```
       $(document).ready(function () {
            var drawcount = 0;
            for (var i = 0; i < imgheight; i++) {
                $("#image").append("<br>");
                for (var j = 0; j < imgwidth; j++) {
                    $("#image").append("<span style='position:relative; color: rgba(" + pixels[i][j].red + " , " + pixels[i][j].green + " , " + pixels[i][j].blue + ", 1);'></span>");

                    switch (drawcount % 18) {
                        case 0:
                            $("#image span").append("/");
                            break;
                        case 2:
                            $("#image span").append("-");
                            break;
                        case 3:
                            $("#image span").append("/");
                            break;
                        case 4:
                            $("#image span").append("-");
                            break;
                        case 5:
                            $("#image span").append("/");
                            break;
                        case 6:
                            $("#image span").append("-");
                            break;
                        case 7:
                            $("#image span").append("(");
                            break;
                        case 8:
                            $("#image span").append("8");
                            break;
                        case 9:
                            $("#image span").append("8");
                            break;
                        case 10:
                            $("#image span").append(")");
                            break;
                        case 11:
                            $("#image span").append("-");
                            break;
                        case 12:
                            $("#image span").append("\\");
                            break;
                        case 13:
                            $("#image span").append("-");
                            break;
                        case 14:
                            $("#image span").append("\\");
                            break;
                        case 15:
                            $("#image span").append("-");
                            break;
                        case 16:
                            $("#image span").append("\\");
                            break;
                        case 17:
                            $("#image span").append("  ");
                            break;
                    }

                    //$("#image").append("</span>");
                    drawcount++;
                }
            }
        });
```

However, now the `<br>` tag isn't working (as before). However, the colors are working.

Comment: I'm not sure I believe that what you say is happening is really happening. Also, there's a far better way to do what that code is doing. You should create a map from the numbers to the strings.

Comment: Also you should of course check for errors in the browser console.

Comment: It works fine without `$("#image").append("<span style='color: rgba(" + pixels[i][j].red + " , " + pixels[i][j].green + " , " + pixels[i][j].blue + ", 1);'>");` After adding that and the `</span>` later on, it breaks the loop and doesn't add color.

Comment: There **must** be a better way to do this... Have you considered an object lookup instead of a switch statement? I'm sure you could reduce that code by half (at least).

Comment: what does the JavaScript console say? There is not a problem with the .append() method in itself, but what you are feeding into it.

Comment: This is definitely the fastest way. I just want to append a character with color. I used the `<span>` tag for the color, but it broke the script.

Comment: JavaScript console is completely silent.

Comment: You have a syntax error in your JSON string, and for whatever reason you're looping from 0 to 80 and 0 to 106, but have only 34 entries in the array you're looping through.

Comment: I didn't want to add all of the values, as there were a lot. Sorry about that. I think I figured it out with the answer that was left but has disappeared. I'm checking something right now.

Comment: I got it fixed, but now my `append("<br">);` tag has stopped working. Is there a conflict with `<span>` and `<br>`? I did not think there was.

Comment: you mean something like http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/NtE65/2/

Comment: there are multiple problems where, 1. `pixels` is suppose to be a 2 dimensional array with 80 rows and 106 columns

Comment: 2. the way in which you are appending the span is wrong.

Comment: in the above fiddle I have fixed the second problem... but the first one you need to fix it by changing the data structure

Comment: It's fine in the original. I mentioned earlier that I shortened it for the post as it was rather long. I noticed you looked through a character string instead of using a switch. I like the switch method. Still, I don't understand why `$(#image).append("<br>")` is working on your but not on mine. I'll update the code. Aside from the switch, it's practically the same. The `<span>` tag is being appended fine, just now the `<br>` is not being appended.

Comment: @Jamil if you like the switch method follow http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/NtE65/1/

Comment: it should work :( ... can you check the dom using dom inspector tools to see whether it is actually getting added?

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Would you happen to know why it doesn't work with the regular `$.append()` method? (As in here: http://jsfiddle.net/NtE65/4/)

Comment: By the way, just as a side note, you can group `case` statements here is a fiddle to show you what I mean: http://jsfiddle.net/DZq2w/

Comment: @Jamil http://jsfiddle.net/NtE65/4/ does not work because `pixels` in there is actually an one dimensional array, that contains objects. Also, your `$span` variable is undefined.